# In-app billing doesn't work on Nexus S

Tags: android, google-play, billing

I'm testing the in-app billing sample code - Dungeons. It doesn't work properly on the device I have (Nexus S, 2.3.3).

Does the Nexus S have a problem with the In-app Billing?

My debug messages are below:

```
03-04 10:10:39.199: INFO/BillingService(28888): CheckBillingSupported response code: RESULT_BILLING_UNAVAILABLE
03-04 10:10:39.199: INFO/Dungeons(28888): supported: false
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, their sandbox testing environment for in-app billing is not ready yet :/. [Everybody](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/318e43185f556724/fd60e3b077091a15?#fd60e3b077091a15) is getting that error message so far.

Comment: Thanks a lot. appreciate your answer

Comment: The sandbox testing environment for in-app billing is now available.

Answer (score 0):

No one outside of Google knows what's going on with it, and they aren't talking yet. Check out [this](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/android-developers/MY5DGF9VZyQ/discussion) and [this](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Android+Market/thread?tid=331d1590e7ae94db&hl=en).

Comment: Thanks a lot. appreciate your answer

Comment: The sandbox testing environment for in-app billing is now available.

Comment: where it is available ? please share complete information javacaptain. you are the captain of our sinking ship :)